# Rails view dependent on time

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to have a div in my view, that shows a piece of text, if the current time is between 9am-5pm GMT, Monday-Friday. But a button if it's outside of that time.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
# Time.now.utc may work 
now = Time.now.in_time_zone('GMT') as well
if time.wday.in?(1..5) && time.hour.in?(9..16)
  # show text
else
  # show button
```

Make sure you modify this code for the templating engine you use (ERB or HAML) appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You have helpers for time and day like `Time.now` to get the current time and `Time.now.wday` that returns the integer corresponding the week day. Just compare then with your rule in your view and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can check something like `@open = (1..4).include?(Time.now.wday) && (9..17).include?(Time.now.hour)`
You get true, or false. Now, you are able to use `@open` to show the button (false), or the text (true)